# Err occurred using ioctl to control my network card!

Tags: 11.10, networking

Recently I installed Ubuntu11.10 instead of the old one in my computer.

But an odd bug occurred during I used the IOCTL to control my network card using the code like this:

```
struct ifreq ifr;
int socketFd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
strncpy( ifr.ifr_name, m_NDISDevName.c_str(), IFNAMSIZ ) ;
if ( ioctl(socketFd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr ) < 0 )
{
    cout<<"_SyncNetInfoToSys device  down!!"  <<endl;
    _Cleanfd( socketFd ) ;
    return false ;
}
if( ifr.ifr_flags |~(IFF_UP) )
{
    ifr.ifr_flags |= IFF_UP ;
    ioctl(socketFd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr ) ;
}

//Set IP addr
struct sockaddr_in sin;
sin.sin_family = AF_INET ;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( IPv4NetInfo.ipAddr.c_str() ) ;
cout<<_SyncNetInfoToSys ipv4 addr !!"  <<   IPv4NetInfo.ipAddr <<endl;
memcpy( &ifr.ifr_addr, &sin, sizeof( struct sockaddr_in )) ;

if( 0 == ioctl(socketFd, SIOCSIFADDR, &ifr ) )
{
    cout << _SyncNetInfoToSys   set ipv4 addr succ!!"  <<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<_SyncIPv4NetInfoToSys   set ipv4 addr fail!!" <<endl;
    _Cleanfd( socketFd ) ;
    return false ;
}
```

ioctl always return false under the Ubuntu11.10.The same code is good under the Ubuntu10.04.

Another odd phenomenon happened, I can reproduce the bug every time I used the code below,But after I upgrade the system and install gcc to compiler code .the bug can not be reproduced .

I have contrast the depend lib in the two situation, the libc.so in two situation are different.

But I replaced the newer one in the bad system ,I can reproduce the bug again.

I'm confused about this!!!

Wish someone can help me!!